# How can I adjust the scroll speed of my mouse manually?

Tags: 10.04, 64-bit, mouse-scroll

I have a wireless mouse device and I would like to speed-up the scrolling. I found a hint that tell us to install gpointing-device-settings.

Unfortunatelly this program is not working in Lucid.Trying to running it one get a segmentation fault error, so I went here to ask how to manually speed up scroll ?

gsynaptics is also not working for me.

Comment: can anyone correct the misprint on the title ?

Comment: What you want me to change??

Comment: Hi Karthick I guess DoR made the correction. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're gonna have to compile a short program, but take a look at this guy's attempt to [increase the scroll speed by X](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10406312#20). If you need help with this, I'd take it to http://superuser.com or http://stackoverflow.com. If you do ask a question somewhere else, put a link here so future questioners can learn!